# Rank one linear map

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I want to solve this question.

> Let $S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ have rank $1$. Prove that for all $v \in V$, there exists $f \in V^*$ and a $w \in W$ such that $Sv = [fv] w$.

This is my attempt.

> Since $S$ has rank $1$, $\dim \text{range } = 1$, so $\text{range } S = \text{span}(\tilde{v})$ for some $\tilde{v} \neq 0$, $\tilde{v} \in V$. Given $v \in V$, we can write $v = a\tilde{v}$ for some $a \in F$. Then
> $$Sv = S(a \tilde{v}) = \tilde{w}$$
> for some $\tilde{w} \in W$.

I do not know how to proceed from here. I know $f$ maps from $V$ to $F$, and I know $T$ will produce so me vector in $W$, so $f(v)$ is a scalar multiple of a vector in $W$. How to construct this $w$, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\dim(\operatorname{range}S) = 1$, we have $\operatorname{range}S = \operatorname{span}(w)$ for some $w \in W \setminus \{0\}$. Now, choose a linear function $g : W \to F$ such that $g(w) =1$, and consider $f:= g \circ S$. Then, for $v \in V$, write $S(v) = aw$ for some $a \in F$, and finally note that $f(v) = g(S(v)) = g(aw) = ag(w) = a$.